# Oracle Rest API multiple rows

Tags: oracle, rest, plsql, oracle-ords

I have to create a GET type of API and I have to connect two tables.

For example, I have the following tables:

Table 1:

- customer_id: {001}
- first_name: {f_name}
- last_name: {l:name}

Table 2:

- customer_id: {001} {001}
- street: {A street} {B street}
- zip_code: {1234} {1234}
- city: {xxxx} {xxxx}
- country: {xx} {xx}

If I connect the two tables I get the following result:

```
{
        "customer_id": 001,
        "first_name": "f_name",
        "last_name": "l_name",
        "street": "A street",
        "zip_code": "1234",
        "city": "xxxx",
        "country": xx       
    }
{
        "customer_id": 001,
        "first_name": "f_name",
        "last_name": "l_name",
        "street": "B street",
        "zip_code": "1234",
        "city": "xxxx",
        "country": xx       
    }
```

This is beacuse the table2 has two rows with the customer_id:"001".

But I want this kind of result:

```
{
    "customer_id": 001,
    "first_name": "f_name",
    "last_name": "l_name",
    "address": [
        {
            "street": "A steet",
            "zip_code": "1234",
            "city": "xxxx",
            "country": xx
        },
        {
            "street": "B street",
            "zip_code": "1234",
            "city": "xxxx",
            "country": xx
        }
    ]
}
```

It seems like a simple query won't work here. Has anybody ideal how should I create this GET type of API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be created using a simple `SELECT` statement for your GET API. You need to use the `CURSOR` command to create nested arrays within your JSON object. An example of what you need can be seen below.

:p_customer_id in the example below is some sort of input parameter from your API.

```sql
SELECT t1.customer_id,
       t1.first_name,
       t1.last_name,
       CURSOR (SELECT t2.street,
                      t2.zip_code,
                      t2.city,
                      t2.country
                 FROM table2 t2
                WHERE t2.customer_id = t1.customer_id)    AS address
  FROM table1 t1
 WHERE t1.customer_id = :p_customer_id;
```

Comment: Thank you! It is so simple and so perfect!!!

Answer (score 1):

We're going to use a CURSOR in the query.

First the tables and data:

```
CREATE TABLE CUST (
    CUSTOMER_ID INTEGER,
    FIRST_NAME  VARCHAR2(20),
    LAST_NAME   VARCHAR2(20)
);

ALTER TABLE CUST 
    ADD CONSTRAINT CUST_PK PRIMARY KEY ( 
    CUSTOMER_ID  
    );

CREATE TABLE ADDY (
    CUSTOMER_ID INTEGER,
    STREET      VARCHAR2(20),
    ZIPCODE     VARCHAR2(5),
    CITY        VARCHAR2(20),
    COUNTRY     VARCHAR2(20)
);

ALTER TABLE ADDY 
    ADD CONSTRAINT CUST_ID FOREIGN KEY 
    ( 
     CUSTOMER_ID
    ) 
    REFERENCES CUST 
    ( 
    CUSTOMER_ID 
    ) 
    ON DELETE CASCADE 
    NOT DEFERRABLE NOVALIDATE 
;

insert into CUST values (1, 'Jeff', 'Smith');
insert into addy values (1, 'Chowning Place', '00001', 'Blacksburg', 'USA');
insert into addy values (1, 'Inkberry Ct', '00002', 'Apex', 'USA');
```

Then we can build the REST API.

Our template is cust_address/:id, and we're going to do a GET on that.

The SQL behind the GET handler:

```
select customer_id,
       first_name,
       last_name,
       CURSOR(
                select street,
                       zipcode,
                       city,
                       country
                from ADDY O
                where C.customer_id = O.customer_ID
       ) address
from CUST C
where customer_id = :id
```

Putting that all together, our TEMPLATE/HANDLER combo is defined like this in ORDS (as shown in SQL Developer Web)

[image]

Then we call the API - just in our browser:

[image]

You'll need to either turn paging off for a Collection Query (set to 0), or you'll need to define your handler as a Collection Item.

*Disclaimer: I'm an Oracle employee and the product manager for Oracle REST Data Services.*

Comment: I am getting an error, ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected CHAR got CURSOR, but it worked after calling from the POSTMAN thanks

Comment: If i use this example the Open API 3.0 Documentation is wrong. I Can not see the properties from the nested Json. Can I fix this?

Comment: @Jensk some of that may be opaque to ORDS...but this would be a separate question